# Predict on Multiclass classification model from Typescript

Tags: python, typescript, tensorflow

I have done the AI Alg in Python. and it gets as parameteres: age, mobilityrange, gender(1,0). I want to predict the given data from the website made in angular typescript and display the results.
this is the code:

```
        async evaluateModel() {
        const modelURL: string = './../../assets/models/model.json';
        let a = [this.ageVar, this.mobility, this.selectedGender];
        let img: tf.Tensor<tf.Rank.R1> = a;

        await tf.loadGraphModel(modelURL).then(model => {
        const output: any = model.predict(a);
        const results: number = output.argMax(1).dataSync()[0];
        console.log(results);
    })
  }
```

I get this error, when giving a as parameter

Argument of type '(Number | Food2[] | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NamedTensorMap | Tensor | Tensor[]'.   Type '(Number | Food2[] | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'Tensor[]'.     Type 'Number | Food2[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Tensor'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Tensor'.